# How to store values in an array to a variable on MPLAB?

Tags: c, microcontroller, mplab

The following code works fine on CodeBlocks compiler but on MPLAB C18 compiler I don't get the same results. I am using PIC18 microcontroller.

**Code**

```
    int d[6];
    int all;

    d[0] = 6;
    d[1] = 4;
    d[2] = 8;
    d[3] = 0;
    d[4] = 0;

    all =  10000*d[0] + 1000*d[1] + 100*d[2] + 10*d[3] +  d[4];
    printf("%d", all);
```

**Output on CodeBlocks**: 64800

**Output on MPLAB**: -816

What is exactly the problem? Shouldn't this code work fine? Thanks!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Size in bytes is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects that have the type `int` aren't guaranteed to be able to store values beyond `-32767` or `32767`. Your Code::Blocks implementation happens to extend this range, but your MPLAB C18 implementation (which isn't really a valid C implementation, by the way) doesn't. What you're seeing in your MPLAB implementation is undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow. Use an `unsigned` type, and/or a wider type, such as `long` or `long long`. Don't forget to modify your printf format specifier accordingly. `%u` for `unsigned int`, `%ld` for `long`, `%lu` for `unsigned long`, `%lld` for `long long`, etc...

Comment: What would be a fix to this?

Comment: I put the fix in the answer.

Comment: You are the boss. I used unsigned and it worked. Thanks for adding more details about the specifier, it was useful.

Comment: @Ammar: You'll probably find it still overflows at 65536... However, that's a well-defined behaviour as opposed to an undefined behaviour. I'd seriously suggest using an `unsigned long`...

Comment: Sounds very good, thanks for letting me know. The max I would want is 86400.

Comment: @Ammar Then `long` is definitely suitable, as it is guaranteed to be able to represent values between `-2147483647` and `2147483647` (and possibly more, depending upon the choices made by your implementation).

Comment: I am trying to use `long int` but it's not working well. I have 86400 in the array, the output gives me 20864. I am using `%ld` as the specifier. what did I do wrong?

Comment: Who knows? I can't see your minimal testcase... If I had to hazard a guess, I would say that your mistake was neglecting to read "*2.3 Constants*" from the second edition of K&Rs "The C Programming Language". Perhaps you'll find the rest of the book interesting, too! Will you show me your testcase, please?

Comment: I got it to work, I just forgot to define the D variable as `long`.

Comment: @Ammar Ah! Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

according to this [link](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014) , Your MCU is 8-bits system. so the length of the integer of your system is 16 bits. when you simulate your code with **CodeBlocks**, you are running your code with a 32-bits system ( or 64-bits system ) and the size  of integer is 32 bits. so you will not get the same results. because in your MPLAP system you are overflowing the integer size

Comment: What are the alternatives?

Comment: Huh? Length of an integer is 8 bits? Then how is it able to store the value `-816`? MCU bitsize isn't the least bit relevant to C compiler `int` size. To clarify: `int` is always *at least* 16 bits in width.