# Data Types with PIC18?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mplab

Which data type do I use to store the following value ?

**Value**: 86400

**code**:

```
int d[6];
unsigned int all;
d[0] = 8;
d[1] = 6;
d[2] = 4;
d[3] = 0;
d[4] = 0;

all =  10000*d[0] + 1000*d[1] + 100*d[2] + 10*d[3] +  d[4];
printf("%u", all);
```

If I copy this code to CodeBlocks, it works fine. However, on MPLAB C18 compiler I would get a different result.

**CodeBlock Output**: 86400

**MPLAB Output**: 20864

How do you fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question here? - [Previous Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403009/how-to-store-values-in-an-array-to-a-variable-on-mplab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits, it may be e.g. 16 bits (i.e. have values from 0 to 65535 for `unsigned int`). This is the case here. You need to use the `long` type here.

Comment: I used long too and I got the same result of 20864 which is strange.

Comment: @Ammar You need to use `long` for _both_ variables.

Comment: @Ammar And of course you need to modify the `printf` format to `"%lu"`.

Comment: You are probably correct, I don't have the PIC18 to confirm it now but I will tomorrow. If I am using `long` shouldn't my specifier be just `%l`?

Comment: @Ammar No, The `l` in the format is just a extra modifier, that tells the `printf` function that the value is "long" (which can differ depending in the actual type specification).

Comment: Ok so my variables **d** and **all** should be declared as `long` and in the `printf` statement I should use `%lu`, correct?

Comment: @Ammar Well, `all` should be `unsigned long` but otherwise it's correct.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow and rate the answer. I appreciate your help so much!